# how to put nested quote inside each other three times in (javascript and ap.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, href, quote

in this code in each loop  it should create new  href and give it id= (the number of o variable) but the problem that  I put double quote inside single quote .

```
    for (o = 0; o < count; o++) {

 $('#'+o).prepend(' <td class="col-lg-2">' +

 '<a href="#" id="o"  onClick="Confirm()" runat="server"     
onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click" class="tableicontoolbar"datatoggle="tooltip"data-placement="top" title="Edit" > ' +
' <img src=\"../images/icon-edit.png\"></a> ' +
   ' </td>');
}
```

I tried many solution but  none work

Comment: Looks fine, but you don't need the `\ ` infront of the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `\`s, and ignore the fact that your string contains `"`s, they don't matter, and runat="server" and onServerClick has no purpose on the client side.

```
for (o = 0; o < count; o++) {
 $('#'+o).prepend(' <td class="col-lg-2">' +
 '<a href="#" id="id_'+o+'" onClick="Confirm()"   
 class="tableicontoolbar" datatoggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">' +
' <img src="../images/icon-edit.png"></a> ' +
   ' </td>');
}
```

You could also remove the `"`s as they are not needed:

```
for (o = 0; o < count; o++) {
 $('#'+o).prepend(' <td class=col-lg-2>' +
 '<a href=# id=id_'+o+' onClick=Confirm() 
class=tableicontoolbar datatoggle=tooltip data-placement=top title=Edit>' +
' <img src=../images/icon-edit.png></a> ' +
   ' </td>');
}
```

Also note, that ID's can not be numeric.  It may work in some browsers, but IDs can not begin with a number, so I've prefixed them with id_ for you.